# Difference between 可能 and 能

Tags: grammar, usage

I’ve always wonder what is the difference between the word 可能 and 能. I know it both means can, possible but is there any difference between them?

Comment: 可能= possible ; 能= can/ able to. They are different words

Comment: "can" in English has multiple meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally **[能](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%83%BD) (néng) talks about *capability*, whereas [可能](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD) (kěnéng) talks about *possibility***.

Often 能 is used where "capability" takes on a practical sense (not necessarily about being physically able to do something).  Typically, 可能 is used when deciding if something is a suitable thing to do.

We do the same thing in English: *I can swim* (capability) vs. *I can swim in Summer* (possibility).

### 能 and 不能

> 我能[游泳](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B8%B8%E6%B3%B3)。
>   <sup>Wǒ néng yóuyǒng.</sup>
>   I am capable of swimming.

This literally implies I am physically capable of swimming.  It doesn't express whether or not I want to go swimming, if I'm allowed to go swimming, and if swimming is a suitable activity (although some of this will be clear from context).

A example where 能 describes a literal capability is:

> 罗根不是他的真名,并且还**不能游泳**。  ([source](https://wx.abbao.cn/a/8631-8ab0919f6f78440e.html))
>   <sup>Luōgēn bùshì tā de zhēnmíng, bìngqiě hái bùnéng yóuyǒng.</sup>
>   Logan is not his real name, and he cannot swim.

An example where 能 describes a practical capability is:

> 戴隐形眼镜**能游泳**吗？  ([source](https://jingyan.baidu.com/article/ce09321b375e402bff858f29.html))
>   <sup>Dài yǐnxíng yǎnjìng néng yóuyǒng ma?</sup>
>   [If someone] wears contact lenses, can they go swimming?

Of course, wearing contact lenses has no effect on one's ability to swim.

### 可能 and 不可能

> 你可能游泳。
>   <sup>Nǐ kěnéng yóuyǒng.</sup>
>   You could possibly go swimming.

This indicates the possibility of going swimming; the person we're saying this to may or may not be able to swim.  An actual example is:

> 你**可能游泳**或者骑自行车 ([source](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_6455b6f30100ihnj.html))
>   <sup>Nǐ kěnéng yóuyǒng huòzhě qí zìxíngchē</sup>
>   You could go swimming or ride a bike

Another example is:

> 春节期间的水温比较低，我觉得**不可能游泳**。 ([source](http://www.mafengwo.cn/wenda/detail-1980603.html))
>   <sup>Chūnjié qíjiān de shuǐwēn bǐjiào dī, wǒ juédé bù kěnéng yóuyǒng</sup>
>   During Spring Festival, the water temperature is comparatively low, I feel it is not possible to go swimming.

In this example, we could change 不可能游泳 to 不能游泳 to talk about a practical impossibility.

---

*Note*: I'm a Chinese learner too.  I tried to ensure this is correct, but please let me know if I've made a mistake I'm unaware of.

Comment: You are quite right. I couldn't have a better one.

Comment: I think 能 can speak to capability in a nominal sense too (i.e. 風能，技能，etc). 可 cannot be used this way afaik.

Answer (score 2):

So you're right about 能. [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E8%83%BD%0D%0A) defines it as:

> can / to be able to / might possibly / ability / (physics) energy

But, 可能 on the other hand has a different set of meanings: [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD) defines it as:

> might (happen) / possible / probable / possibility / probability / maybe / perhaps / CL: 個｜个

---

Simply put:

- 能 = able
- 可能 = maybe

Here's two examples using 去 (go):

你明天能去吗？
Are you able to go tomorrow?

他可能去也可能不去。
He might go and then again he might not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why no one pointed out the obvious issue with the picked answer's example phrase. It's just plain wrong.

> 你可能游泳。

Like the second answer pointed out, it's not a verb!

> might (happen) / possible / probable / possibility / probability / maybe / perhaps

Nobody in China would say "You possibly swim".

And the picked answer's own translation uses "go"

> You could possibly go swimming.

-> 你可能会去游泳。